# Remove specific character from string start c#

Tags: c#, regex

I would like to know how can i do with a regex in c# to remove from the string start the character 0 so i i receive as input:

```
000004000 after the regex i get: 4000
W050 after the regex i get: W050
```

I would appreciate your help.

Best regards.

Comment: Have you tried anything?

Answer (score 9):

Why use regex? Just use [TrimStart](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.string.trimstart(v=vs.110).aspx) and keep it simple. At least, your code will be readable:

```
 var str = "000004000";
 var trimmedResult  =  str.TrimStart('0');
```

Output: "4000"

Answer (score 2):

You could try the below code which remove all the leading zeros.

```
string str = "00004000";
string result = Regex.Replace(str, @"^0+", "");
Console.WriteLine(result);
```

[IDEONE](http://ideone.com/eJ23LF)

Answer (score 0):

Match with this regex:

```
/[^0\s]\S+/
```

[See a regex demo!](http://regex101.com/r/aE8rO9/2)

Answer (score 0):

`TrimStart` is the way to go. However here is another alternative using linq:

```
var result = new string(str.SkipWhile(c => c == '0').ToArray());
```